# Remote sensing gdal

Tags: python, gdal

I am trying to open an Sentinel 3 Image in python using  the following code:

```
image='F:\backup\sentinel 3\S3A_OL_2_WFR____20170705T082340_20170705T082640_20170706T153313_0179_019_292_2340_MAR_O_NT_002.data\CHL_NN.img'
d=gdal.Open(image)
d.ReadAsArray()
```

but I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\algorithms\inputs\Sentinel_3.py", line 25, in <module>
    d.ReadAsArray()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try using double slash in your path

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that it can't read 'd' as an array because it's NoneType, meaning that something went wrong in the line before where you used gdal.Open() and it didn't produce a legitimate output.

Try checking your path - correct folder and file names. You might also want to check your slashes as Francisco Raga suggested, and if that doesn't work see if removing the space in your path name fixes this.